# ico files displayed but not jpg/png, {% load staticfiles %} breaks the code

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Can't make my app "see" images.
Was able to use static files with Jinja2 but not Django. 
If I put my images directly in my main app directory, I can display favicon.ico when declare it in app.yaml like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
```

But this declaration doesn't work for other file types:

```
- url: /image\.jpg
  static_files: image.jpg
  upload: image\.jpg
```

Inserting {% load staticfiles %} into template breaks the code.

This line is accepted but no image is displayed (unless I use favicon.ico)

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `<img src="/image.jpg" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct

```
- url: /image\.jpg
  static_files: image.jpg
  upload: image\.jpg
```

and your images should be "visible" in static directory:

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

Just make sure that these declarations are before you reference by package name:

```
- url: .*
  script: your.app
```

In this case you won't need to {% load staticfiles %}. But your 500 error could be because of using older django versions as before 1.4 it was {% load static %}